Unauthorized access to Search Console with unused tokens and the errors that started after
I received an email from Search Console indicating that two individuals, using different emails, had owner access to our Search Console. I removed both emails, and the Search Console indicated that these emails had been granted access using an unused token. I attempted to remove this unused token from the Search Console, but despite each attempt, it still shows that the token exists.
Since this incident, we’ve encountered several errors in our Search Console, such as mismatched URLs on AMPs.
Additionally, unrelated metadata is appearing in our snippets, like this example: ‘Link Situs Slot Gacor 2024 Resmi Terpercaya Hari Ini Dengan RTP Tertinggi.’ This text isn’t present in our source code but is being displayed in the Search Console inspector.
I would appreciate any advice or assistance on resolving this problem.
I tried to remove these two emails and also disabled my Tag Manager scripts for added security.

It actually looks like outside interference!
Especially the text related to gambling confirms this.
How many accounts do you have? Check in Google Admin Console that only you have permissions to grant access, etc.
And I'd also recommend: try using domain records (DNS) to confirm permissions and remove the token.
